# Updating an XML with a list of changes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML

```
var xxx = new XDocument(new XElement("Log",
new XElement("Set", new XAttribute("id", 1), new XElement("File", new XAttribute("path", "path1"))),
new XElement("Set", new XAttribute("id", 2), new XElement("File", new XAttribute("path", "path2"))),
new XElement("Set", new XAttribute("id", 3), new XElement("File", new XAttribute("path", "path3")))
));

<Log>
    <Set id = 1>
        <File path = "path1">
    </Set>
    <Set id = 2>
        <File path = "path2">
    </Set>
    <Set id = 3>
        <File path = "path3">
    </Set>
</Log>
```

and a List of changes

```
var sets = new[] { new { id = 4, Path = "path4" }, new { id = 5, Path = "path2" } }.ToList();
```

I want to update XML with a list by "path" attribute: remove "set" elements with path not in list, not to touch existed paths and add new ones. Actually parse list into new XML but keep old ids (and other attributes in real task).

The result should be

```
<Log>
    <Set id = 2>
        <File path = "path2">
    </Set>
    <Set id = 4>
        <File path = "path4">
    </Set>
</Log>
```

I can do it with loops but how to do it with LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the children with the new elements, since you're so keen on not using a loop.

```
xxx.Root.ReplaceAll(
    sets.Select(x =>
        new XElement("Set",
            new XAttribute("id", x.id),
            new XElement("File",
                new XAttribute("path", x.Path)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: No, it will update old id = 2 to id = 5. I want to keep old id = 2 where path = path2